# Using [tag:tagname] in markdown doesn't work as documented in help

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

The [markdown help snippet about Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags) says:

> See the many questions tagged [elephants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elephants) to learn more.
>
> The tag will automatically be linked to the corresponding tag info
>   page.

Actually the tag does not get linked to the corresponding tag info page, but instead to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elephants

with the title: `show questions tagged 'elephant'`

It looks like either the markdown interpreter should be fixed to produce the link to the info page, or if it's intentional, the help should be updated to reflect what the code does.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147591/tag-markdown-links-to-the-question-list-but-the-help-claims-it-links-to-the-tag

Comment: Still not fixed...

Comment: Also link markdown. That'd be nice.

Answer (score 3):

> or if it's intentional, the help should be updated to reflect what the code does.

After this kind of delay, let's just assume that it is intentional; documentation updated for next deploy.